# Using a deep fryer for fish

Tags: fish, deep-frying

Does using a deep fryer for fish effect 
1: the taste of other things fried in the oil. 
2: how frequently the oil needs to be replaced or stored between uses.

In short do I need separate oil for deep frying fish and vegetables, pastries... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Yes, and Yes.

Citations:

- [If you plan on offering seafood as well as other proteins you will want a separate cooker to prevent the dreaded fishy taste transfer.](https://ultrafryer.com/choosing-the-right-deep-fryer/)
- [Typically, once you fry fish in the oil, it tastes like fish, which might not be a flavor you want in your fried chicken.](https://www.quora.com/Do-deep-fryers-allow-the-use-of-the-same-oil-for-different-types-of-food-such-as-fish-meat-and-poultry)
- [A fish and chips concept risks not only rancid flavors](https://www.restaurantbusinessonline.com/advice-guy/keeping-fry-oil-fresh-fish-chips-edition) from frying oil overdue for a change, but also unwanted odors—and more importantly proteins—from fish and breading that could have cross-contact with the fries.

Comment: Incidentally, fish isn't the worst food for the lifetime of your oil.  Sugary things are.